# Ошибка undefined reference to + list<T>::iterator it?

Tags: c++, исключения, fstream, шаблоны-с++, итераторы

Компилятор будто не видит конструктор с параметрами и деструктор, но все есть. Я не понимаю откуда эта ошибка берется. Объясните пожалуйста!

Код ошибки:

```
main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\../main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `ControllerIOFStream<UserAccount>::ControllerIOFStream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
C:\Users\../main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `ControllerIOFStream<UserAccount>::~ControllerIOFStream()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Создание объекта класса ControllerIOFStream:

**MAIN.cpp**

```
ControllerIOFStream<UserAccount> CIOUserAccounts(str);
```

Класс описан в двух файлах: `ControllerIOFStream.h` и `ControllerIOFStream.cpp`

**ControllerIOFStream.h**:

```
/*
 * ControllerIOFStream.h
 *
 *  Created on: 12 нояб. 2017 г.
 *      Author: Дмитрий
 */
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ControllerIOFStream {
private:
    string path;
public:
    ControllerIOFStream();
    ControllerIOFStream(string);
    ~ControllerIOFStream();
    list<T> readFile(list<T>);
    list<T> writeFile(list<T>);
};
```

**ControllerIOFStream.cpp**:

```
/*
 * ControllerIOFStream.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 12 нояб. 2017 г.
 *      Author: Дмитрий
 */

#include "ControllerIOFStream.h"

template<class T>
ControllerIOFStream<T>::ControllerIOFStream():
        path(""){
}

template<class T>
ControllerIOFStream<T>::ControllerIOFStream(string path) :
        path(path) {

}

template<class T>
ControllerIOFStream<T>::~ControllerIOFStream() {
}

template<class T>
list<T> ControllerIOFStream<T>::readFile(list<T> List){
    ifstream inputStream(path);
    size_t size;
    T buf;
    inputStream>>size;
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
        inputStream>>buf;
        List.push_back(buf);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return List;
}

template<class T>
list<T> ControllerIOFStream<T>::writeFile(list<T> List){
    ofstream outputStream(path);
    outputStream<<List.size()<<"\n";
//for????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
//  for(list<T>::iterator it=List.begin();it<List.end();++it){
//      outputStream<<*it<<"\n";
//  }
    outputStream.close();
    return List;
}
```

Есть еще вопрос: почему не работает код в методе writeFile(list List)?

Сам код под кучей знаков вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В очередной раз те же грабли...

Нельзя реализацию шаблона выносить в отдельный .cpp-файл! Откуда при компиляции этого (`ControllerIOFStream.cpp`) файла знать, **что** (с каким параметром шаблона) будет инстанцироваться в другом файле?

А в этом другом файле (`main.cpp`) - откуда знать, **как** инстанцировать шаблон, если нет доступа к коду реализации?

То, что у вас в `ControllerIOFStream.cpp` - должно быть перенесено в .h-файл. Или нужно в нем явно инстанцировать `ControllerIOFStream<UserAccount>`...

Comment: то есть все шаблонные классы реализуются сразу в хедере?

Comment: Как правило, да. Или с явным инстанцированием.